# How to add value to an object from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, hashmap

I have an object like the one

```
var obj = {
    key : firstLevel()
}
```

Now I want the value of `obj.key` to be returned from a function say `firstLevel()`.
The issue in my case is that, the `firstLevel()` function embeds a callback function. And I want to return the response from it as the value for `obj.key`.

The function definition is as follows

```
var firstLevel = function(){
     esClient.search(function(response){
     console.log(response); //I want to return this response as the value for obj.key
     })
}
```

Comment: i think you have to take it in a variable and then pass it to JSON object.

Comment: @Shubham
I think the scope of the variable is an issue here..

Comment: esClient.search this should be synchronous or you will assign value before callback. Or you can  move esClient.search another function and assign value or create object after callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstLevel = function(){
    var result;
    esClient.search(function(response){
        result=response;  
    })
    return result;
}
```

Comment: if search function is asynchronous, result is always null.

Comment: I think the requirement is to get the value of response to obj.key.

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstLevel = function(){
     var res;
     esClient.search(function(response){
         console.log(response); //I want to return this response as the value for obj.key
         res = response;
     });

     while(!res) {}
     return res;
}
```

this will work, but it will freeze your window.